# how do I make node_save work on newly defined column

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

so I added a column into the drupal node table and added it into hook_schema...if I do a node_load, it will load the new column just fine but if I modify the column in the node and then do a node save, it wouldn't save it into the DB...is there a way to specify node_save to also save into that new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not extend core tables.

Instead, define your own table, reference the nid and then save/delete/update your additional field(s) in the appropriate hook_nodeapi() implementations.